# Favicon isn't working on root website and only works on specific sites after refreshing

Tags: html, css, favicon

In my index.php file I have:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
```

And in assets/images I have the two files ("favicon-16x16.png" and "favicon-32x32.png"). What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I go to specific pages on my websites and refresh I see the favicon. But it doesn't show on the root page and it only only show on some other pages if I refresh.

Another thing I noticed is that this problem didn't happen when my index.php file was called index.html. However I have to name the file index.php because I'm hosting through Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The favicon rel should be defined as `rel="shortcut icon"`like this:

And also make sure the path file is correct for every page. If your root file is in the same directory i.e. inside your `assets` folder, then the above updated code should work but if your index is outside your assets folder, then you need to change your favicon path file to something like `href="assets/images/favicon-32x32.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what is causing this issue, but here is a checklist:

- Use absolute paths, eg. `/images/favicon-32x32.png`, instead of relative paths, eg. `images/favicon-32x32.png`. Else you might have issues due to pages in different directories.
- Makes sure your links are valid. For example, if your HTML code contains `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">` and your web site is `http://example.com`, then type `http://example.com/images/favicon-16x16.png` in the address bar of your browser: does it displays the icon?
- Browsers are very tough regarding favicon caching. If the favicon is not configured correctly, you browser might display it anyway because it cached it during a (successful) previous attempt. Even if the favicon is configured correctly, your browser might not display it, at least immediately, because of failed previous attempts. As a workaround, you can add a kind of version to your URL. For example, `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png?v=2" sizes="16x16">` and change it whenever you try something else. That will force your browser to consider the picture no matter what it encountered previously.
- Because of this same caching issue, you might want to try with another browser, just to make sure your cache is not messing up.
- While debugging your favicon, display either your browser's network logs (Firebug with Firefox, Dev tools with Chrome...) and/or your server's logs (eg. `access.log` with Apache) to understand what's going on. Again, this might reveal the dreadful caching issue: you try many things but your browser won't reload anything.
- Browsers can have different behavior in local environments regarding favicon. Are you accessing your files directly, ie. from the file system? If so I suggest you to switch to a web server environment.